# add_rewrite_rule image from /images/site2/favicon.ico to /favico.ico

Tags: php, functions, multisite, rewrite-rules

Please Friend all, help me!

How add_rewrite_rule in multisite subdomain from images via functions.php not .htaccess

My Image Path https://cdn.domain.com/images/site2/favicon.ico

But I want change url to https://cdn.domain.com/favicon.ico, How setting this url with rewrite rules in PHP.

Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want change url to https://cdn.domain.com/favicon.ico, How setting this url with rewrite rules in PHP.

You can't. That's not how WordPress rewrite rules work.

`add_rewrite_rule` is used for mapping pretty permalinks into the form `/index.php?queryvar=value&etcetc`.

Most servers don't even load WordPress to handle requests like that for assets and skip PHP/WordPress completely for performance reasons. Doing this will require Nginx/Apache level changes above/outside of WordPress